# Github Actions: Show branch tag after manually build with workflow_dispatch and selected branch

Tags: github, github-actions

when i start a workflow manually with the workflow_dispatch trigger and a selected branch, the branch tag is not set in the overview. Any idea how i can do that?

When the workflow is started after pushing the tag is shown.

Thanks ...

```
name: Build Master parent

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        ref: 'master'
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
...
```

[image]